# Display Alert Message at run time in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In following code Cheque Amount is less then (quautity * rate) then display alert message.
XHTML code :

```
<p:dialog id="invoiceDialog" header="Add Invoice"
                widgetVar="addInvoice" minHeight="40" showEffect="explode"
                hideEffect="fold">
                <table border="1" id="dialogTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Description Of Goods Or Services" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="HSN Code" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Quantity" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Rate" /></td>
                        <td><p:outputLabel value="Percentage Discount" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p:inputText id="description"
                                value="#{invoiceBean.descriptionOfGoodsOrService}" cols="45"
                                required="true" label="Description"
                                requiredMessage="Description Require Entry"
                                disabled="#{invoiceBean.descriptionOfGoodsOrService != null}" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.hsnCode}" size="6" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText id="quaintity"
                                value="#{invoiceBean.quantity}" size="3" styleClass="Alingment"
                                required="true" label="Quantity"
                                requiredMessage="Quantity Require Entry" autocomplete="off" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText id="rate" value="#{invoiceBean.rate}"
                                styleClass="Alingment" required="true" label="Rate"
                                requiredMessage="Rate Require Entry" autocomplete="off" /></td>

                        <td><p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.percentDiscount}"
                                size="2" styleClass="Alingment" autocomplete="off" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <h:panelGroup id="mode">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;"
                                value="Mode Of Payments" />
                            <p:selectOneRadio value="#{invoiceBean.modeOfPayment}"
                                layout="pageDirection">
                                <f:ajax render="mode" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cash" itemValue="Cash" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cheque" itemValue="Cheque" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
                            <p:outputLabel value="Enter Bank Name :" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.bankName}"
                                disabled="#{invoiceBean.modeOfPayment == 'Cash'}" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Enter Cheque Number :" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.chequeNumber}"
                                disabled="#{invoiceBean.modeOfPayment == 'Cash'}" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="Total is :" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{invoiceBean.chequeAmount}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <p:dataTable value="#{invoiceBean.transactions}"
                                var="transaction">
                                <p:column headerText="Mode Of Payment">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.modeOfPayment}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Bank Name">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.bankName}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Amount">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.chequeAmount}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Balance">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.balance}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:summaryRow>
                                    <p:column colspan="3">
                                        <p:outputLabel value="Remaining Balance" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.balance}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:summaryRow>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Save New Invoice"
                    action="#{invoiceBean.addRow}" update=":form:invoiceTable growl"
                    process="@form invoiceTable" onclick="PF('addInvoice').hide();">
                    <f:ajax render=":form:invoiceTable" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
            </p:dialog>
```

Following managed bean code it is used to store transaction related data :

```
 public void addRow() {

    int lastBalance, currentBalance, storeBalance;
    transaction = new Transaction();
    invoiceProductsServicesDetail = new InvoiceProductsServicesDetail();
    invoiceDao = new InvoiceDao();
    transactionDao = new TransactionDao();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("form:invoiceTable");
    UIComponent uiTable = ComponentUtils.findParentForm(facesContext,dataTable);
    final AjaxBehavior behavior = new AjaxBehavior();

    try {
        amount = (rate * quantity);
        if(chequeAmount <= amount){
            transactions = transactionDao.getTransactions(invoices.get(0).getId());
            if (transactions.size() != 0) {
                setTransactions(transactions);
                lastBalance = transactions.get(transactions.size() - 1).getBalance();
            } else {
                lastBalance = 0;
            }
            currentBalance = chequeAmount - amount;
            storeBalance = lastBalance + currentBalance;
            transaction.setModeOfPayment(modeOfPayment);
            if (modeOfPayment.equals("Cheque")) {
                transaction.setBankName(bankName);
                transaction.setChequeNumber(chequeNumber);
                transaction.setBalance(storeBalance);
            } else {
                transaction.setBalance(storeBalance);
            }
            transaction.setChequeAmount(chequeAmount);
            transaction.setReceiptNumber(String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()));
            transactionDao.setTransaction(transaction, invoices.get(0).getId());
            this.transactions = transactionDao.getTransactions(invoices.get(0).getId());
            RowEditEvent rowEditEvent = new RowEditEvent(uiTable, behavior, invoiceProductsServicesDetail);
            rowEditEvent.setPhaseId(PhaseId.UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES);
            dataTable.broadcast(rowEditEvent);
        }else{
            //Diplay Alert Message that "Producats/Services total amount Must greater than your cheque amount"
        }
    }
    } catch (AbortProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Then after transaction data store otherwise not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry for that, but my code is very lengthy.

Comment: I know. That's why I posted that link. It explains in detail how you can create a proper snippet for in the question. One way would be just saving the current code in version control and then removing as many as possible lines as long as the problem still exhibits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put In the else part

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage();
facesMessage.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);      
facesMessage.setDetail("Producats/Services total amount Must greater than your cheque amount");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
return null;
```